# Moving linux installation to another partition on same drive

Tags: linux, grub, fstab

I have followed [these instructions](https://superuser.com/questions/307541/copy-entire-file-system-hierarchy-from-one-drive-to-another/713017#713017?newreg=f39a7597befa44a3a6fe570cf887a296) to move my linux installation from /dev/sda5 to /dev/sda7. 
The copy things went perfect.

I have edited /boot/grub/grub.cfg so that it boots from /dev/sda7 and it works.
I have also edited /etc/fstab on /dev/sda7 so that root (/) dir is pointed to UUID of /dev/sda7.

But after booting, when doing mount it still show / is mounted to /dev/sda5
What should I do to make it mounted to /dev/sda7?

My fstab on /dev/sda7:

> UUID=af7b38bc-f8d0-400a-b42a-c4904210213a /               ext4    errors=remount-ro 0       1

My ls -l /dev/disk/by-uuid show:

> lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 10 Th10 16 17:52 af7b38bc-f8d0-400a-b42a-c4904210213a -> ../../sda7

# mount

> /dev/sda5 on / type ext4 (rw,errors=remount-ro)

Comment: Did you also run `update-grub` after changing its config file?

Comment: @Hennes: yes.. I did.

Comment: Is it possible you are still booting from */dev/sda5*? if you enter GRUB menu at boot, do you options to boot from (at least) different OSes?

Comment: @MariusMatutiae: I boot from /dev/sda7, but yes, thanks to your suggestion, I double checked what's in /boot/grub/grub.cfg and found out that in the kernel line it still says `linux /boot/vmlinuz-3.16.0-34-generic root=UUID=7919b2c3-ab89-4317-9326-e2b8fd540102` which is the UUID of /dev/sda5. I changed it to sda7 UUID and things is fine now.  So even if I modified fstab, the parameter in grub.cfg prevails!

Comment: Things like your last comment are why I use grub-customizer (GUI app on Ubuntu, or from a live image if necessary). It takes care of most things like this - or makes them easy to see and edit. It can also rewrite the MBR if you need to change boot loaders.

Comment: Since this is solved, one of you should make it an answer.