# Archive a complete Linux server

Tags: linux, virtual-machine, hyper-v, archiving

Story: Our hosting partner runs our VM in Hyper-V. This VM has now been superseded by a new VM-server. Before we are going to shutdown the old VM I would like to create an archive/backup, that I can boot/install in case we need something.

How can I archive/copy/backup the full Linux server, so that I can restore it later?

- Host: Hyper-V
- Guest: CentOS 7.2

Comment: Download the virtual hdd and the configuration of the vm

Comment: You could also tar the entire filesystem, makes it easier to go through individual files.

Comment: The VM is a web server with PHP and MySQL. If I need it one day, it's likely that I need a bootable version with MySQL running. Is it possible to restore a Linux system from tar?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Copy entire file system hierarchy from one drive to another](https://superuser.com/questions/307541/copy-entire-file-system-hierarchy-from-one-drive-to-another)

Comment: Would Veeam work for this? Especially as it zips the image and can mount it in its own internal VM for recovery if needed.

Comment: Could be a solution. I hoped that there would be a solution built into linux