# File-based backup of encrypted Linux systems?

Tags: backup, bootable-media, disk-encryption, clonezilla, luks

I learned that tools such as `clonezilla` cannot omit free blocks when the disk is encrypted, which is a huge problem, since the backup drive always needs to have *at least* the same size as the source drive - even if the latter contains mostly free space! This is impractical and not how backups should work.

Let's assume a standard Linux installation with a partition structure such as [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/U6sAl.png) (encrypted, LUKS on LVM). How do you create a bootable, file-based backup?

**Idea:** Use `cp -a` to copy all files from the source to the backup drive.

=> *How to reproduce the partition structure from the terminal? Are there Linux built-in tools for this job? And will `cp` copy files that are currently open/in use (hot transfer)?*

The idea, obviously, is to create a slim & sleek Bash script that could be run, ideally, directly from any running source system:

```
- Creating backup -

1.) Mount empty USB flash drive to running source system
2.) Run Bash script (hot transfer of all files and partition structure)
3.) Bootable, file-based backup is created


- Restoring backup -

1.) Mount backup USB flash drive to empty host machine
2.) Boot the backup system
3.) Run Bash script (partitioning of host drive, hot-transfer of all files)


...finished! Reboot, remove backup USB flash drive, enjoy restored system.
```

Note: If I'm correct, the resulting backup will **not** be encrypted. But this seems to be a necessary trade-off in order to use `cp` from within the unlocked system and thereby avoid creating these gigantic bit-by-bit images/clones. Plus, an encryption can always be added afterwards.

Comment: Yes, you can copy each file or folder at a time. However, this is **far** slower than dd or other backup tools. Also, since each file takes up integral allocation units, it would take more room than a compressed backup image. You would also need to copy system files, including boot sectors, to have a safe image in case of disaster.

Comment: You can have the backup encrypted.  You would need to have it use LUKs, then mount it, then copy the files.

Comment: Also, its better to encrypt then copy rather then try convert to encryption later - both because in the Interim you won't have protection, but also its possible some unencrypted data won't actually be encrypted when you convert it - especially on SSD's

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out that **`rsync`** is the perfect tool of choice. It supports the [complete](https://superuser.com/a/307542/941977) and [hot](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/599850/311155) transfer of an entire file system from within a running system:

`rsync -avxHAX / /dev/[backup_drive]/`

The encryption/decryption issue is [solved](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/599561/311155) by unlocking the encrypted disk beforehand:

`cryptsetup luksOpen /dev/[source_drive] && rsync -avxHAX / /dev/[backup_drive]/`

The remaining task is to reproduce everything *outside* the scope of `rsync`, i.e. *outside the file system*, meaning the boot sector (= first 512 Bytes on the drive) containing the bootloader and partition tables. For this, `dd` or `ddrescue` could be used:

`cryptsetup luksOpen /dev/[source_drive] && rsync -avxHAX / /dev/[backup_disk]/ && dd if=/dev/[source_drive] of=/dev/[backup_drive] bs=446 count=1`

Here, `bs=446` is used instead of `bs=512` in the assumption that the backup drive and partitions will have a different size, therefore [omitting](https://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/howto-copy-mbr) the partition table and signature bytes.

This should result in a **complete**, **hot-transferred** (from the running system), **bootable**, **sparse** (file-based) **Linux disk backup** done from the terminal.

To do: Encrypt the backup!